# Max angle of beam against surface (ultrasonic sensor)

Tags: localization, ultrasonic-sensors

I am trying to localize a robot within a rectangular room (182cm x 243cm) with completely black walls (so IR sensors and LIDAR are out of the question). I am trying to figure out if I can position enough ultrasonic sensors around my robot so that I can calculate the distance to each wall and the orientation of the robot at any heading or position within the room (assuming the bot does not get too close to any of the walls).

What is the maximum angle at which an ultrasonic sensor can reflect against a wall and still get an accurate reading?  I am using these sensors specifically, which have 1mm resolution:

[Maxbotix HR-LV-MaxSonar-EZ4 High Performance Sonar Module](https://www.robotshop.com/en/maxbotix-ez4-high-performance-sonar.html?gclid=CjwKCAjw1KLkBRBZEiwARzyE7wcDgX3jBnfT2amCZb5UB4GD63ZgvmlGvW8mB2ZJqh3NJEiufkn37RoCxLwQAvD_BwE)

Any other tips on localization in this kind of environment?

Comment: the smallest number of sensors required is one

Comment: observation: you described the walls ..... you said nothing about the floor or the ceiling ...... perhaps you can use IR to detect the edge of the floor or ceiling

Comment: That could work -- sense when the IR reading from the floor disappears (as the beam hits the black wall) -- thank you.  Unfortunately, I was more looking for a strategy that would allow me to determine position and heading at any position within the room.